# In C, is it a fair coding practice to typedef an array type?

Tags: c, coding-style, typedef, conventions

I guess there must be a duplicated question here but I couldn't find it. I'm recently working on a C project and, while trying to leave the code as concise as possible, I considered typedef-ing a consistently-used array with a certain type.

As an example, suppose the array of a structure type `entry` has always the fixed length of `MAX_N_ENTRIES`. I'd like to reduce the redundancy by rewriting the code;

```
struct entry ents[MAX_N_ENTRIES];
```

to this code;

```
typedef struct entry entry_arr_t[MAX_N_ENTRIES];
entry_arr_t ents;
```

What I'm concerning about is that, as the array type obviously should be handled in a different way to any primitive types in C, this kind of typedef-ing can cause confusion in the future, making it look like an alias of primitives.

Comment: I think it’s a good idea. You’ve even made it explicit in the naming.

Comment: @Ry-♦ Well that's true, but I'm having a feeling of using typedef only for primitive (or its tentative) types.

Comment: One issue is that if passing to a function `void f(entry_arr_t x)` there is no way to pass it as a pointer-to-const  (if you use `const` qualifier, that qualifies `x`, not the pointed-to element type). The usual "solution" to this is to have another typedef `const_entry_arr_t` or something. Also note if a function takes `const entry_arr_t *` then there is no implicit conversion from `entry_arr_t *` which is pretty annoying

Comment: @M.M that was the point I missed, the constantness. I'll look over this idea...

Comment: Aside from the `const` issues, the abstraction would be "leaky" unless you hid all subscripting operations behind an interface (functions or macros).  IOW, if the user of the type has to be aware of its "array-ness" to use it properly (such as to index into it), then you should *not* hide the type behind a typedef.

Comment: "is it a fair coding practice" Yes.  "Could code do that way?", No.

Comment: @JohnBode I guess this is in line with my original concern.

Comment: If the arrayness is an implementation detail that the user of the type is not supposed to see, this causes a real mess when you want to pass the type as an argument to a function. See `va_list` in C for how much headache this can cause.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to create a typedef for an array type -- and there's even an example in the Standard C library, namely the `jmp_buf` type that's used with `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

It's usually considered poor style, however, because type names are usually assumed to refer to first-class types that you can do every ordinary first-class-type thing with, and in particular: assign them.  But of course you can't assign arrays in C, because they're not first-class types.

In other words, given the typedef in your question, a later programmer might assume that it would be possible to write

```
entry_arr_t ents1, ents2;

...

ents1 = ents2;
```

But of course that assignment would fail.

The fact that you've included "`arr`" in the typedef name does indeed mitigate this concern, making it less likely that the hypothetical later programmer would make the bad assumption.